# Ordered list using page views

Tags: php, wordpress, html-lists

i'm trying to create a "most popular" section for a school news wordpress website based on page views, the current code being used to repeat the stories produced by students is:

```
<div>
<?php query_posts('showposts=10&cat=62'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="technology2">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
</div>
```

code works, but like i stated i was hoping for a numbered 1-10 list.

I have a plug-in that uses

```
<?php print_page_views(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

to get each individual page view count.

Any tips on how to use the page-count code to generate the list?

P.s. a bouns would be if you could limit the list of articles posted in the last couple months?

Comment: Might get better answers on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin does all you want http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts

Comment: Yes! I was going to post that. You can use it as a shortcode, a template tag, or a widget. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

look at the plugin, how it stores the page-views, and then use the query with `"ORDER"` and `"ASC" " DES"` options..